# Combining NGRX with Angular services

Tags: angular, ngrx

There are situations where the cleanest solution to a use-case seems to be a combination of NGRX and a service. Is this wise, or does it violate the 'single source of truth' principle of NGRX?

For example, if I am using NGRX to build a shopping app I might have a store which includes:

- An array of all products (objects) with name, product ID, cost etc.
- An array of product IDs (strings or numbers) for the subset of products currently in the shopping cart.

The cart component would likely use a selector which filters all products by product IDs in the cart, but what about other components that need to know when an item is removed?

An array of 'removed' items is not going to be stored in the state, so one approach is to listen for a 'REMOVE_ITEM' action, and then update a service with the product IDs of the removed items. Components can then subscribe to this service and take appropriate action.

Is this good practise? If not, what is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 1):

NGRX propose some single 'source of truth' principe, but you are free to make changes if it's the cleanest solution for your app.

About your solution of storing data in services. It will works fine when you are using constant data.

But when multiples components will have to update this data you will probably encounter change detection and improper update issues, that you could solve with NGRX Store.

You can also check this : https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-redux-ngrx-rxjs/

Comment: Thanks for the input Benjamin. I'm going to use pairwise to compare the two most recent iterations of the state and use that to identify what has changed. It feels a bit long-winded, but more in keeping with ngrx principles than a separate service?

Comment: Hello, why you need to use pairwise to compare the two most recent operations?     this._store.select('your-products') returns an Observable, so you can subscribe to it.

Note that when you subscribe explicitly to an observable, you should take care of unsubscribing when you component gets destroyed.

Maybe I don't understand your problem, can you provide your code ? :)

Comment: Thanks Benjamin... it's more of an opinion based question than a code question - maybe that's why I've got a downvote :)

In the example, I need to work out which items have been removed from the cart - pairwise does this cleanly by providing the last two instances of the state, which can then be compared for any differences (e.g. removal of an ID from the cart).

Answer (score -1):

Taking the shopping cart example specifically, I believe the solution which most respects the 'single source of truth' principles of NGRX is to use the [pairwise](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/pairwise) operator to subscribe to the most recent (n) and second most recent (n-1) iterations of the state:

```
this.activeFilters$.pipe(pairwise()).subscribe(state => {
  const currentState = state[0];
  const previousState = state[1];
  // Compare currentState with previousState to identify changes e.g.
  const removedItems = state[1].cart.filter(productID => state[0].cart.indexOf(productID) === -1);
});
```

currentState and previousState can then be compared for differences, which will indicate the most recent change.

**Updated 3 years later...**

The sample pairwise code above could be set up as an NGRX selector, which would bring [various benefits](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors).

More generally (and with the benefit of more experience), while it's not unacceptable to have an independent service working alongside NGRX, I think it's usually unnecessary.